# Is there a method to estimate uncertainty in parameter fit of sum of gaussians via scipy.optimize.curvefit?

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, confidence-interval, scipy-optimize

I have a natural spectrum which is fitted to three Gaussians. The multi-Gaussian function which is fitted is this one (taken from some answer given on Stack overflow)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def Gaussian_func(x, *params):
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(0, len(params), 3):
        ctr = params[i]
        amp = params[i+1]
        wid = params[i+2]
        y = y + amp * np.exp( -((x - ctr)/wid)**2)
    return y


pars, pcov = curve_fit(Gaussian_func, xdata, ydata, p,bounds=(0,np.inf),maxfev=3800)

parsmatrix = np.array([pars[x:x+(3)] for x in range(0, len(pars),3)]) 
pcovmatrix = np.array([pcov[x:x+(3)] for x in range(0, len(pcov),3)])
```

The fitted plot is given, but I think that the particulars are not necessary so the data is omitted.
But I would like to estimate, in some manner, how accurate these fitting parameters are. So, is there some way we can use the covariance of the fitted parameters or some such measure to evaluate how certain we can be that the fitted parameters correspond to the "real" parameters? i.e. the real center of each peak. Because one can imagine that the peaks could all be shifted  and still produce a reasonable fitting despite the fact that the one shown is the optimized fitting.

[image: fitted plot]

Comment: it really depends on the nature of the underlying data. Can you describe what is the input for this curve fitting?

Comment: The fitted data is a chemical emission spectrum. I know based one the particulars of this system that there are three peaks in this area, but I am not certain their relative intensities or their locations.

Comment: To get some bound on how correct the fit is, we need a notion of "quantity" of the incoming data. If this spectrum is perfectly reproducible each time, then the fit is perfect and estimating how good it is doesn't make much sense. Is there any variability in the underlying data?